# Adding a standard object as a Frame class attribute with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI using Tkinter that will allow me to interface with some lab equipment.

I would like to have a combo box reference the handles of various pieces of equipment in my "hardware manager".

Currently, in the top-level frame (that is, one below `Root()`), I instantiate the hardware manager as a class atribute.  However, I am having some trouble accessing that information from nested frames.

Below is the test code (to simplify things):

```py
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


class TestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_array = [1, 2, 3]


class TestFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, frMaster):
        Frame.__init__(self, frMaster, bg='gray', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.frMaster = frMaster
        self.testClass = TestClass()
        self.subFrame = SubFrame(self.frMaster)
        self.subFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


class SubFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, frMaster):
        Frame.__init__(self, frMaster)
        self.frMaster = frMaster
        self.sHandle = StringVar()
        self.cbTest = ttk.Combobox(self.frMaster, width=20, justify='left',
                                   values=[0, 1, 2], textvariable=self.sHandle)
        self.cbTest.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='nesw')


root = Tk()
test = TestFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I would like to happen is to use the `test_array` attribute from the `test_class` as the value list for the combo box.  So ideally, the line instantiating the combo box would actually look something like this:

```py
    self.cbTest = ttk.Combobox(self.frMaster, width=20, justify='left',
                               values=self.frMaster.testClass.test_array,
                               textvariable=self.sHandle)
```

This obviously won't work, though, as `self.frMaster` in that instance actually refers to the root window, not the `test_frame` instance.  So I get an attribute error.

I also tried instantiating the `SubFrame` simply with "self" as the master.  This technically works, but it fails to display the combo box.

So, is there a better way to access the data in the `TestClass` instance?  Or, alternatively, how can I get the combo box to display if I pass the `TestFrame` instance as the master to the `SubFrame` instance?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that seems to work is instantiating the test class as `self.frMaster.testClass = test_class()` in the test frame's `__init__` function.  This, while functional, seems a bit "hacky" though.  I have to imagine there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: it is good rule to use `UpperCaseNames` for classes - ie. `StringVar`, `TestFrame`, `SubFrame` -  and `lower_case_names`  for variables - ie. `self.test_frame = TestFrame()`. It helps to recognize Class in code. And it is suggested by PEP8 so many people and tools respect this rule. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Good to know, I will edit the post.

Comment: Seems like `TestFrame._init__()` could simply pass `self.testClass` as an argument to `SubFrame.__init__()` when it creates its `self.subFrame` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest terms possible, if you need the attributes of an object (eg: `test_array` from `TestClass`), you need a reference to that object (eg: the instance of `TestClass`).

There are several ways to do it. The simplest is to pass the reference down to the code that needs it. For example:

```
class TestFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, frMaster):
        ...
        self.testClass = TestClass()
        self.subFrame = SubFrame(self.frMaster, self.testClass)
        ...

class SubFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, frMaster, testclass):
        ...
        self.cbTest = ttk.Combobox(..., values=testclass.test_array, ...)
```

Comment: This may be the way i have to go.  I wanted to try to avoid it, if possible, since I have upwards of 20 SubFrames in the actual code.  Looks like I will just have to suck it up, though.

Comment: @detroitwilly: If you've got that many `SubFrame`s to create, you should probably be doing it in some sort of loop based on the [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of software development.